# An exercise about replicable random variables

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, finance

The following question is an exercise which I have in my course for Financial Mathematics:

Let $h:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be twice differentiable with $h'' \geq 0$. Establish, with the help of Fubini's theorem, the representation

$$h(x) = h(0) + h'(0)x + \int_{0}^{\infty}(x - K)_{+}h''(K)dK.$$

Now assume that in a financial market model (T = 1, d = 1), without arbitrage and such that $S_1 \geq 0$ a.s., all call options are replicable. Is the random variable $f(S) := h(S_1)$ also replicable?

I would appreciate any help here. I am quite lost regarding this question, so I can unfortunately not offer any real approach by myself. Has anybody an idea regarding the two questions in this task?

Edit: just for clarification: We call a random variable f $"$replicable$"$ if $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}$ and there exists a trading strategy $H$ on risky assets such that $f = a + (H.S)_T \ $ $\mathcal{P}$-almost surely. Here, we call $(H.S)_T = \sum_{i=1}^{T}H_i(S_{i+1} - S_{i})$ the stochastic integral of $H$ with respect to $S$.

Comment: the first question begs to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus in some way. have you tried that ? Also, it'd be nice if you could include the definition of "replicable call option" in your question.

Comment: I edited the post with the definition I have been given for a replicable random variable $f$. And yes I thought about it. However the expression $(x - K)_{+}$ gives me some headache, since I don't know what to do here. But my first thought was somehow to approach the first question with the notion that we have $h(x) = h(0) + \int_{0}^{\infty} h'(t) dt$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stratos already gave you an answer for the first part; for replication, observe that your derivative payoff can be decomposed as:

$$h(S_1) = h(0) + h^\prime (0) S_1 + \int_0^\infty (S_1 - K)^+ h^{\prime \prime} (K) dK$$

Assuming interest rates are zero, we may statically replicate by holding $h^\prime (0)$ of the stock and the infinitesimal amount $h^{\prime \prime}(K)dK$ of call options is held with each strike $K$. This gives you a recipe of replication using the risky assets (i.e. stocks and options).

You'll find this referred to in the mathematical finance literature as the Carr-Madan formula.

Comment: Thank you! So $f(S)$ is indeed replicable by your explanation?

Comment: @user1265841 yes

Comment: One last question (even if it may sound stupid): can the term $h(0)$ be interpreted as $a$ (from my original post) and the rest of the expression as stochastic integral $(H.S)_T$? I try to connect your explanation with the knowledge I have aquired so far in the course. So I apologise if I may annoy you

Comment: @user1265841 my answer should be taken as a hint. You can use it to write down the expression as a stochastic integral in terms of dS and dC. E.g. note that $\int_0^1 h^\prime (0) dS = h(0) (S_1 - S_0)$. So $h(0) + h^\prime(0)S_1 = h(0) + h(0) S_0  + \int_0^1 h^\prime (0)dS$. Can you extract your $a$ from there? You can continue your argument using $dC$ with the remaining term

Comment: I understand your computation but for the $dC$ part (which is my $dK$ I assume) I don't know how to handle the term $(S_1 - K)_{+}$ inside my integral. And, can I use the same bounds of integration like you for the second derivative inside my integral? As for the $a$: with the way you did it, I would now assume that $a = h(0) + h(0)S_0$?

Comment: @user1265841 Write the call payoff as $c_1(K) = (S_1 - K)^+$ then note that $c_1(K) = c_0(K) + \int_0^1 dc(K)$...

Comment: So, eventually we get $h(S_1) = h(0) + h(0)S_0 + \int_{0}^{1}h'(0)dS + \int_{0}^{\infty} c_0(K)h''(K) dK + \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}h''(K)dc(K)dK$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint for the first part :** by the fundamental theorem of calculus applied respectively to $h$ and $h'$,

$$\begin{align}h(x) - h(0) &= \int_0^x h'(t)\ dt\\
&=\int_0^x \left[h'(0) + \int_0^th''(K)\ dK\right]\ dt\\
&= h'(0)x + \int_0^x \int_0^t h''(K)\chi_{[0,t]}(K)\ dK\ dt\\
&= h'(0)x + \int_0^x \int_0^\infty h''(K)\chi_{[0,t]}(K)\ dK\ dt\\\end{align}$$

Where $\chi_{[a,b]}(u) := \mathbf 1\{a\le u\le b\}$ is equal to $1$ if $u\in[a,b]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Can you finish now ? (one more hint : $(x-K)_+ =\int_0^{x} \chi_{[?,?]}(t)\ dt $)

Comment: I see. That's why Fubini is needed here. But how  exactly do you get $\textbf{1}\{h''(s) \leq t \}$? I suppose it has to do with the integral going to infinity but I don't completely understand that. And still: the expression $(x -  K)_{+}$ still seems very odd to me in the original problem.

Comment: it should have been $\textbf{1}\{s \leq t \}$, sorry. I edited my post to match the notations of your questions and add one more hint. (and note that so far in my computation I haven't used Fubini theorem !!)

Comment: Yes your last hint made everything very clear. We now want to use Fubini so that we can switch the integrals and then I just use your last hint in order to get the required expression. Is that right?

Comment: However, do you have any ideas regarding the part of the replicability? I am still pretty much lost regarding this question. :-(